# The Knight's Trial

Tags: chess

You've most likely heard of the eight queens puzzle, right? Where you have to place *n* chess queens on an *n* * *n* board so that no queens attack each other (boy, those must be some very angry monarchs!)? Well...what if, instead of queens, you had to place chess knights on an *n* * *n* board?

**What's the maximum possible number of chess knights you can place on a 4 by 4 grid so that no knight can attack at least one knight in one single move? What about a 5 by 5 grid? A 6 by 6? A 7 by 7? Is there even a pattern to the maximum number of knights you can place on an n by n grid so that nobody attacks another knight?** (You don't need to answer that last question, but don't let that stop you from answering it if you really want to! It's just an extension question!)

Edit: And here's another question!

**For an n by n board how many ways are there of placing knights according to the rules given?**

Comment: If you re-post this in the [Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox), it can be adjusted to not be a duplicate, if you're interested.

Comment: We have a close reason called "Needs More Focus" for when there are too many questions in a question. Adding a new question will not make this a non-duplicate; removing the duplicate questions and keeping the new question would.

Answer (score 2):

For a 4 by 4 grid:

[image: 4 by 4 grid chessboard, knights on all black squares or all white squares]

5 by 5 grid:

[image: 5 by 5 grid, kinghts on white squares. They can also be on black squares]

6 by 6:

[image: 6 by 6 grid, knights on white squares or black.]

7 by 7:

[image: 7 by 7 grid, knights on white or black squares]

Why?

> When a knight moves, it moves to a space of a different color (from white to black or black to white). If they are all on the same color, no collision happens.

Pattern: The pictures speak for themselves.

Comment: You can improve your 7x7 solution by one, by replacing the 24 white-square knights with 25 black-square knights.